# Large size file not uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I upload a large file in gb, my debugger doesn't hit the file action on the controller.
The code that I applies is given below:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="108000" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
```

Upload large file size 4  gb in asp. Net core mvc

Comment: That's not code, that's a configuration setting. Post the controller code at least. How is the file uploaded? Through a form? An HTTP request? If a form, post the view as well.

Comment: Uploading large files are normally done via special javascript and .net libraries that send smaller chunks of data, to allow things like progress bars and retry on broken connections etc.  I would recommend you look into that.